# Get items from PageList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am using the project PagedList (https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) on an ASP.NET MVC project and I have the following:

```
PagedList<TestModel> models = _service.Get(2, 20);
```

The service always return a PagedList but I need to create a List with only the items in PagedList and without the paging metadata.

I tried the following

```
IList<TestModel>)models.GetEnumerator()
```

No success. How can a PagedList be converted to List?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time to type a full answer, but have you tried the ToPagedList(int, int) extension method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
using System.Linq;

models.ToList()
```

The return type is `List<TestModel>`.